# Should I be worried about '&' in a returned URL from a web service

Tags: php, rest, drupal-7

I've made a web service in PHP that returns a URL, just a bunch of concatenations of things.  If the accept header is JSON, everything looks great:  `/example/v1/?prod=my.product.is.great&key=1`.  However, if it is xml, it returns something like `/example/v1/?prod=my.product.is.great&amp;key=1`.

My question is, is there anything I can do on the service side to ensure that the & is correct, or is this expected behavior?

Comment: use html_entity_decode

Comment: No worries! Just test it, you will see nothing bad happens

Comment: I wouldn't say its expected behavior, you have something going on in there.  I would review your code and find out whats going on there.  It probably won't affect the request.  If you dump the $_GET request on PHP it doesn't pick up the extra parameter at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely a correct behavior. The **&** sign needs to be encoded when transferred via XML. You can decode it in your client using **html_entity_decode** PHP function for example.

Comment: Thanks.  When I clicked the link, as is, I get an error saying that the key was missing.  Knowing that the client will need to decode that makes me feel better.